# Display date in different color in asp Calendar control

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, calendar

i am using a calendar control. We are getting four different type of date from database and the same will be display on calendar and other date disabled . The four type of date are

```
a) Today
b) First Schedule
c) Second Schedule
d) Third Schedule
```

Today will be highlighted with surrounded by green color circle First Schedule as yellow, Second schedule as Green and Third as fourth as Red color .[image: My Current Calendar that is showing currently].

The code i have tried as below for

```
<asp:Calendar ID="CalScheduleDays" runat="server"   Height="100%" Width="100%" 
                               BorderWidth="1px" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" OnDayRender="CalScheduleDays_DayRender" TodayDayStyle-ForeColor="#FF0000" >          </asp:Calendar>


protected void CalScheduleDays_DayRender(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
                e.Day.IsSelectable = false;                
                CalScheduleDays.SelectedDates.Add(_dates.FirstScheduleDate);
                CalScheduleDays.SelectedDates.Add(_dates.SecondScheduleDate);
                CalScheduleDays.SelectedDates.Add(_dates.ThirdScheduleDate);
            
            if (e.Day.IsSelected)
            {
                  e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
                  e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                  e.Day.IsSelectable = true;
            }

            if (e.Day.IsWeekend)
            {
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
                e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
                e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            }
             

    }
```

Thanks for your help and support for the same.

Comment: if you want to highlight by circles then why have you added back color ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to highlight by circles only then you can add css in code behind like below

```
if (e.Day.Date == dtFirstSchedule)
 {
    e.Cell.CssClass = "dotYellow";
    e.Day.IsSelectable = true;
 }
else if(e.Day.Date==dtSecondSchedule)
 {
   e.Cell.CssClass = "dotGreen";
   e.Day.IsSelectable = true;
 }
else if(e.Day.Date==dtThirdSchedule)
 {
    e.Cell.CssClass = "dotRed";
    e.Day.IsSelectable = true;
 }
else if(e.Day.Date==DateTime.Now.Date)
 {
   e.Cell.CssClass = "dotGreen";
    e.Day.IsSelectable = true;
 }
else
 {
  //do nothing
 }
```

And in css class add below css

```
<style>
        .dotRed {
            height: 25px;
            width: 25px;
            background-color:red;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

       
        .dotGreen {
            height: 25px;
            width: 50px;
            background-color:green;
            border-radius: 100%;
            z-index:-1;
        }

        .dotYellow {
            height: 25px;
            width: 25px;
            background-color:yellow;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
    </style>
```

This will display like below

[image]